# preg_replace regex conflicting with others

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So i have this here

```
<? $regex = array('/@(\w+)/','/#(\w+)/','/((www|http:\/\/)[^ ]+)/');
    $replace = array(
    '<a href="https://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>',
    '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23$1">#$1</a>',
    '<a href="\1">\1</a>'
); ?>

<?= preg_replace($regex,$replace,stripslashes($row['tweet_text']));?>
```

The first two are suppose to turn anything with @ and # into links. This is obviously for twitter. But the third is supposed to turn anything with http or www into a link. But it seems to be conflicting with the first two messing up the links.

How can i make the third one make http or www links without conflicting the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be hacky at best, but you could try this:

```
<? $regex = array('/((www|http:\/\/)[^ ]+)/', '/(?<!>)@(\w+)/', '/(?<!>)#(\w+)/');
    $replace = array(
    '<a href="\1">\1</a>',
    '<a href="https://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>',
    '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23$1">#$1</a>'
); ?>
```

Turn the order around, fixing the links first, then only replace `@` and `#` handles if they are not preceded by a `>` (which they would be if they were already inside an anchor tag).

Comment: @soniccool: Basically, yes. The `(?<!>)` is just an extra precaution.